# Error while running CNN for 1 dimensional data in R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run 1 dimensional CNN in R using `keras` package. I am trying to create one-dimensional Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) architecture with the following specification

[image]

```
library(keras)
library(deepviz)

#create a neural network with a convolutional layer and train the model
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filters=32, kernel_size=4, activation="relu", input_shape=c(100, 10)) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size=2) %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filters=64, kernel_size=4, activation="relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size=5) %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filters=128, kernel_size=4, activation="relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size=5) %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filters=256, kernel_size=4, activation="relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size=5) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate=0.4) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units=100, activation="relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate=0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units=1, activation="linear")
```

But it is giving me following error

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 4 from 1 for 'conv1d_20/conv1d' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,128], [1,4,128,256].

How to solve the error?

Another question, how to optimise the `filters`, `kernel_size`, `pool_size`, `rate`, `units`?
In my question `input_shape=c(100, 10)` is an arbitrary value. How to decide about the input size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many Max-Pooling layers, the max pooling layer reduces the dimension of the inputted vector by factor of its parameter.

Try to reduce the pool_size parameters , or alternatively remove the last 2 max-pooling layers. A value you can try is pool_size=2 for all layers.

As for the parameters you should learn of the meaning of them:
Here you can find an explanation of the convolution layer and max pooling layer parameters like filters , kernel size and pool size:
[Convolutional layer](https://poloclub.github.io/cnn-explainer/)

The dropout layer is a regularization which maximize the effectiveness of the layer weights , every epoch it zeroes different percent (size of "rate" parameter) of the weights . the larger the rate - you have less overfitting but training time is longer. learn about it here:
[Dropout layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/)

The units is the size of the Fully Connected layer.
[Fully Connected layer](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tensorflow-for-deep/9781491980446/ch04.html)

The input shape is a dimensions of your data, when the number of records does not count. In 1d vectors it is (N,C) when N is the vector length and C is number of channels you have, if you have 1 channel it is (N,1).
In 2d vectors it is (Height,Width,Channels).

Comment: Can you try to run my code with your suggestion and see whether it is running correctly? But I want to implement CNN with the configuration given in the image. How to decide about the input size? In my code, it is an arbitrary value?

Comment: I'm not an 'R' expert, but I created an equivalent network with the parameter pool_size=2 in python with keras and it ran without errors.
The input shape (l,c)  is the shape of the input 1d image (because you used the conv1d layer) when the "l" parameter is the length of the vector, and the "c" parameter is the number of channels you have.
If you have 2d images - use conv2d layer with the following input shape (H,W,C) Height , Width and Channel (the channel usually is the color with size of 3 - RGB).

Comment: Actually, my data is not in image format. I can provide you with the data in excel. I am open to Python answer also. You can post it.

Comment: If every data record is a 1d vector size of N, so the input_size should be (N,1).

If the data record is a 2d table size of (H,W) so the input_size should be (H,W,1)

Comment: here is an exapmle in python:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vaLOg-_mRKPYtlCe__DgAVv_OEHMTEyW#scrollTo=HZNhxANKqqhH

Comment: How to decide the values for `filters`, `kernel_size`, `pool_size`, `rate`, `units`? My data dimension is 201 obs. of  2102 variables. Can I run conv2d?

Comment: It looks like the data you described to me is 1d (because the number of records does not count as a dimention) I'll answer about the parameters in my answer.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68418215/valueerror-in-user-code-while-using-keras-model-in-r). It will be great if you help me out.